# How do affinity scheduling reduce the number of TLB misses and page faults

Tags: scheduling, tlb

I am trying to understand how affinity scheduling reduce TLB misses and page faults? Can someone please give me a explanation how this process works? I understand the "affinity scheduling", but can not understand how that can reduce TLB misses and page faults?

Comment: As far as I know affinity sheduling does reduce the TLB misses (do not ask me (yet) how), but it does NOT reduce the amount of page faults. This amount is not affected by this kind of sheduling. I  am investigating in this matter at the moment myself. If I find something useful on my way I will pass that information along to you.

Comment: BTW this is not a question which is meant to be asked here ^^ Stackoverflow is more about problems with the code one wrote and it is not working (properly)...

Answer (score 0):

Affinity scheduling has to do with putting the right thread on the right CPU. Doing so might well reduce TLB misses since these are kept inside each CPU. On the other hand, it has no effect on page faults, since if a page is in memory for one CPU, it is in memory for all CPUs.